Extract posterior for a nested random effect with spread_rvars() from a brms model
I want to extract the posterior distribution from my brms model using spread_rvars() from the tidybayes package. I am able to extract all the parameters, but not the nested random effect.
the structure of my data is:
'data.frame':   2492 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ALive        : int  6 9 9 10 10 1 0 0 8 5 ...
 $ Total        : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ Cl_act       : num  1804 1523 1188 296 18 ...
 $ Lakename     : chr  "15mile" "15mile" "15mile" "15mile" ...
 $ CloneNo      : chr  "Mile_1" "Mile_1" "Mile_1" "Mile_1" ...

My model is:
bf(Response | trials(Total) ~ 1/(1+exp(b*(log(cloride_act)-log(LC50)))),
            LC50 ~ 1+(1|Lakename/CloneNo),
            b ~ 1+(1|Lakename/CloneNo),
            family = binomial(link = "identity"),
            nl=T)

When I use get_variable(fit) %>% dput() I get:
    c("b_LC50_Intercept", "b_b_Intercept", "sd_Lakename__LC50_Intercept", 
"sd_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50_Intercept", "sd_Lakename__b_Intercept", 
"sd_Lakename:CloneNo__b_Intercept", "r_Lakename__LC50[15mile,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[3_Lakes,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Anstruther,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Aquatic_Research_Lab_C,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Arab,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Binghampton,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Carmel,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Celery_Bog_Northwest_Pond,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Chautauqua,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Convict,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Cunningham_Forest,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Darby,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Eels,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Elbow,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[ESL,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Flathead_Lake,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Glamor,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Gott,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Grandview,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Hambly,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Haynes,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Henshaw,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Jeffrey,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Julia,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Kasshabog,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Lohi,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Long,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Loughborough,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Lux9,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Medicine,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Mendota,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Mississauga,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Ontario,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Parkers,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Pencil,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Praire_Oaks_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Prairie_Oaks_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Purdue_Wildlife_Area,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[RedChalk,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Round,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Salmon,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Sans_Chambre,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Scugog.(Sc10),Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Scugog.(Sc11),Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Scugog.(Sc2),Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Scugog.(Sc3),Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Shaw3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[SLB,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[South_Otter,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Southwest_Woods,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Sucker,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Tanners,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Verona,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Wabasso,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__LC50[Wilcox,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__LC50[Zeeb,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[15mile_Mile_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[3_Lakes_3Lakes_7,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Anstruther_ANS-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Aquatic_Research_Lab_C_ARLC_10,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Arab_Arab_11,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Arab_Arab_19,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Arab_Arab_33,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Arab_Arab_40,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Arab_Arab_9,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Binghampton_BING_2,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Carmel_Carm_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Carmel_Carm_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Carmel_Carm_6,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Celery_Bog_Northwest_Pond_CB.NWP_7,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH10Z,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH1Y,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH4Y,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH5X,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH6P,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH6W,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH7Z,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH8X,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH9Y,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Chautauqua_CH9Z,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Convict_Conv_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Cunningham_Forest_CF_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Darby_Darby_40,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Darby_Darby_42,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Darby_Darby_43,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Eels_EEL-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Elbow_Elbo_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[ESL_ESL_12,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[ESL_ESL_14,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[ESL_ESL_19,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[ESL_ESL_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[ESL_ESL_4,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Flathead_Lake_Flath_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Glamor_Glam_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Gott_Gott_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Grandview_Gdview_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Grandview_Mile_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Hambly_Hamby_31,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Haynes_Haynes_27,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Henshaw_HShaw_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_57,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_62,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_69,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_87,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Julia_Julia_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Julia_Julia_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Julia_Julia_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Kasshabog_KAS-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Lohi_Lohi_7,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Long_Long_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Loughborough_Loughb_6,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Lux9_Lux9_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Medicine_Med_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Mendota_Mend_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Mississauga_MIS-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Ontario_Ontario_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Parkers_Park_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Pencil_PEN-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Praire_Oaks_2_Oaks2_19,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Praire_Oaks_2_Oaks2_25,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Praire_Oaks_2_Oaks2_27,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Prairie_Oaks_3_Oaks3_15,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Prairie_Oaks_3_Oaks3_22,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Prairie_Oaks_3_Oaks3_6,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Purdue_Wildlife_Area_PWA_10,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[RedChalk_RdCha_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Round_Round_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Salmon_SAL-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Sans_Chambre_SCham_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Scugog.(Sc10)_Sc_10,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Scugog.(Sc11)_Sc_11,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Scugog.(Sc2)_Sc_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Scugog.(Sc3)_Sc_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Shaw3_Shaw3_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[SLB_SLB_10,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[SLB_SLB_13,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[SLB_SLB_14,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[SLB_SLB_6,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[SLB_SLB_8,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[South_Otter_SOtter_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Southwest_Woods_SWood_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Sucker_SUC-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Tanners_Tan_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Verona_Verona_81,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Wabasso_Waba_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Wilcox_Wilcox_46,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Zeeb_Zeeb_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[Zeeb_Zeeb_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[15mile,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[3_Lakes,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Anstruther,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Aquatic_Research_Lab_C,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Arab,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Binghampton,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Carmel,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Celery_Bog_Northwest_Pond,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Chautauqua,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Convict,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Cunningham_Forest,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Darby,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Eels,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Elbow,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[ESL,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Flathead_Lake,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Glamor,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Gott,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Grandview,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Hambly,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Haynes,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Henshaw,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Jeffrey,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Julia,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Kasshabog,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Lohi,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Long,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Loughborough,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Lux9,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Medicine,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Mendota,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Mississauga,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Ontario,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Parkers,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Pencil,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Praire_Oaks_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Prairie_Oaks_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Purdue_Wildlife_Area,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[RedChalk,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Round,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Salmon,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Sans_Chambre,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Scugog.(Sc10),Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Scugog.(Sc11),Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Scugog.(Sc2),Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Scugog.(Sc3),Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Shaw3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[SLB,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[South_Otter,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Southwest_Woods,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Sucker,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Tanners,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Verona,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Wabasso,Intercept]", "r_Lakename__b[Wilcox,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename__b[Zeeb,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[15mile_Mile_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[3_Lakes_3Lakes_7,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Anstruther_ANS-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Aquatic_Research_Lab_C_ARLC_10,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Arab_Arab_11,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Arab_Arab_19,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Arab_Arab_33,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Arab_Arab_40,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Arab_Arab_9,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Binghampton_BING_2,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Carmel_Carm_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Carmel_Carm_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Carmel_Carm_6,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Celery_Bog_Northwest_Pond_CB.NWP_7,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH10Z,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH1Y,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH4Y,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH5X,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH6P,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH6W,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH7Z,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH8X,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH9Y,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Chautauqua_CH9Z,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Convict_Conv_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Cunningham_Forest_CF_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Darby_Darby_40,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Darby_Darby_42,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Darby_Darby_43,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Eels_EEL-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Elbow_Elbo_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[ESL_ESL_12,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[ESL_ESL_14,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[ESL_ESL_19,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[ESL_ESL_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[ESL_ESL_4,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Flathead_Lake_Flath_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Glamor_Glam_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Gott_Gott_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Grandview_Gdview_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Grandview_Mile_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Hambly_Hamby_31,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Haynes_Haynes_27,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Henshaw_HShaw_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_57,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_62,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_69,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Jeffrey_Jeffrey_87,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Julia_Julia_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Julia_Julia_2,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Julia_Julia_3,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Kasshabog_KAS-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Lohi_Lohi_7,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Long_Long_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Loughborough_Loughb_6,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Lux9_Lux9_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Medicine_Med_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Mendota_Mend_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Mississauga_MIS-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Ontario_Ontario_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Parkers_Park_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Pencil_PEN-1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Praire_Oaks_2_Oaks2_19,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Praire_Oaks_2_Oaks2_25,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Praire_Oaks_2_Oaks2_27,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Prairie_Oaks_3_Oaks3_15,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Prairie_Oaks_3_Oaks3_22,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Prairie_Oaks_3_Oaks3_6,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Purdue_Wildlife_Area_PWA_10,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[RedChalk_RdCha_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Round_Round_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Salmon_SAL-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Sans_Chambre_SCham_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Scugog.(Sc10)_Sc_10,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Scugog.(Sc11)_Sc_11,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Scugog.(Sc2)_Sc_2,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Scugog.(Sc3)_Sc_3,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Shaw3_Shaw3_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[SLB_SLB_10,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[SLB_SLB_13,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[SLB_SLB_14,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[SLB_SLB_6,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[SLB_SLB_8,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[South_Otter_SOtter_1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Southwest_Woods_SWood_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Sucker_SUC-1,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Tanners_Tan_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Verona_Verona_81,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Wabasso_Waba_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Wilcox_Wilcox_46,Intercept]", "r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Zeeb_Zeeb_1,Intercept]", 
"r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[Zeeb_Zeeb_2,Intercept]", "lprior", "lp__", 
"accept_stat__", "stepsize__", "treedepth__", "n_leapfrog__", 
"divergent__", "energy__")

To extract the draws and calculate the posterior predictions my code is:
posterior_clone <- fit_clone %>%  
spread_rvars(b_LC50_Intercept, b_b_Intercept),
               r_Lakename__LC50[Lakename,Intercept],
               r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo,Intercept], 
               r_Lakename__b[Lakename,Intercept],
               r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[CloneNo,Intercept]) %>% 
  mutate(LC50_lake = b_LC50_Intercept + r_Lakename__LC50[Lakename,Intercept]) %>% 
  mutate(LC50_clone = b_LC50_Intercept + r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo,Intercept]) %>% 
  mutate(b_lake = b_b_Intercept + r_Lakename__b[Lakename,Intercept]) %>% 
  mutate(b_clone = b_b_Intercept + r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[CloneNo,Intercept])

But I get :
Error in r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo, Intercept] : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo, Intercept] :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo, Intercept] :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used

I also tried :
posterior_clone <- fit_clone %>%  
spread_rvars(b_LC50_Intercept, b_b_Intercept),
               r_Lakename__LC50[Lakename,Intercept],
               `r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo,Intercept]`, 
               r_Lakename__b[Lakename,Intercept],
               `r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[CloneNo,Intercept]`) %>% 
  mutate(LC50_lake = b_LC50_Intercept + `r_Lakename__LC50[Lakename,Intercept]`) %>% 
  mutate(LC50_clone = b_LC50_Intercept + `r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo,Intercept]`) %>% 
  mutate(b_lake = b_b_Intercept + r_Lakename__b[Lakename,Intercept]) %>% 
  mutate(b_clone = b_b_Intercept + `r_Lakename:CloneNo__b[CloneNo,Intercept]`)

But then I get:
Error: The variable `r_Lakename:CloneNo__LC50[CloneNo,Intercept]` was not found in the model.

It is probably a syntax problem, but I can't find how to fix it.
Thank you!
